# Accordion menu - how to stop all buttons opening when one is clicked?

Tags: javascript, accordion

Is there a simple way to adapt the code below so only the button clicked will run the slideDown / slideUp code below? I've got 5 buttons with the html below.

I know the code isn't ideal but I'm a beginner and it's for a test so I'd like to adapt the below so I can defend it when questioned

Html:

```
<div class="accordion">   
<button type= "button" class="question">
<p>This is a question</p>
</button>
</div>  
<div class="answer">
<p>This is the answer</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.question').on('click', function(){
  
  if ($('.answer').is(':visible')) {
    $('.answer').slideUp()
  } else {
    $('.answer').slideDown()
  }
})
```

Comment: Could you add your code as a Snippet so it will run on this site? Also, you mention 5 buttons, but I only see one in your HTML. Could you add those in too so that we can see the full extent of the issue?

Comment: Thanks Richard - it's up at: http://artlogic-test-site.superhi.com/

(Still a work in progress btw!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify which answer

```
$('.question').on('click', function(){
    let answer = $(this).siblings('.answer') 
    //Or depend on the position find() closest() next()
    if (answer.is(':visible')) {
        answer.slideUp()
    } else {
        answer.slideDown()
    }
})
```

In fact now I saw the structure - best way is to set data-id attribute to the question and for the answer class = answer answer-1.
The selector will be let answer = $('.answer-' + $(this).data('id'))

Comment: Thanks Llian! I'm a complete idiot though, for your first solution would I have to define sibling in the html? Or how would find() or next() work?

Comment: check the jQuery docs - next(<optional selector>) gets the first sibling in matched elements after the current.
find(<selector>) will give you the matched elements nested in the current - some nested children for example. Depends on your structure.

Answer (score 0):

Bit old now but in case helpful to anyone looking for an answer, this is the code I used:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

  const $answer = $(this).parent().next() 
  const $triangle = $(this).find('p') 
  if ($answer.is(':visible')) {
    $answer.slideUp()
    $triangle.text("\u25BC")
  } else {
    $answer.slideDown()
    $triangle.text("\u25B2")
  }
})
```